# Losing ASP.Net Session in popup window from Windows Forms Web Browser Control

Tags: winforms, session, popup, webbrowser-control

I'm using Web Browser Control in a windows form (vb.net) to display one of our website (ASP.NET) as a part of the windows application. Everything works fine, but when I've a popup window from the website page, I'm loosing the ASP.Net session. I've used extended version of web browser control to have *Navigate2* event to catch the popup window and open it in a windows form web browser control again, then it works, but I have problems with size of the popup and close button in the html popup window.
Please let me know if there is a work around for loosing session in Web browser control popup window in asp.net.
**How can I open a popup window from my winforms web browser control without loosing the session?**

Comment: I could not find an answer for this solution, managed internally with restoring session on popup.

Comment: Hello I am having the same problem of loosing a session from my winforms web browser control.I save this session inside a aspx page. Can you please give me some hints on what you did for this